# Support for Ultra High Speed MicroSD cards

Tags: external-sd, motorola-milestone

I am going to buy a new MicroSD card for my Motorola Milestone. The phone has Cyanogenmod 7. The upper limit as [told by the manufacturer](http://developer.motorola.com/products/milestone-a853/) is 32GB, and because they got cheaper now, I'm going to buy the maximum possible. However, there are those new types of cards called “Ultra High Speed” which, I believe, weren't available when the phone came out.

Questions: Will those cards work with my device? Do they need any special support from the OS? Will I benefit from extra speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The new UHS-I card

Your phone comes with a microSDHC form factor, and according to Scandisk, their cards are  compatible:

- [SanDisk Ultra® microSDXC™ UHS-I card](http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/microsd/ultra-class10-with-adapter/): <sup>see specifications tab</sup>

  > Available capacities: 8GB,16GB, 32GB, 64GB
  >
  > Performance/speed: Up to 30MB/s read speed; write speed lower
  >
  > Compatibility: Compatible with all microSDHC [or microSDXC ]supporting host devices
- [SanDisk Extreme Pro® microSDHC™ UHS-I card](http://www.sandisk.com/products/memory-cards/microsd/extremepro-uhs-i/?capacity=16GB): <sup>see specifications tab</sup>

  > Available capacities: 8GB,16GB
  >
  > Performance/speed: Up to 95 MB/s (633X) read speed; write speed up to 90 MB/s (600X)
  >
  > Compatibility: Compatible with all microSDHC supporting host devices

*Since the form factor remains the same, there's no problem here.*

## Your Device

Your device, while capable of reading, will be unable to take advantages over this new card speeds.

Mainly because this technology is new and the OS simple wasn't prepared for it.

**On a personal note:** Don't spend your money with this card on that specific phone. You'll have no gain from it.

Comment: I actually bought the first one you mentioned, mostly because the price of it was about the same as of a slower class-10. And, as predicted, it works. Thank you.

Comment: Same price == nice ;)

Answer (score 5):

> Will those cards work with my device?

Yes, I believe SDHC UHS-I (Ultra High Speed) cards are backwards compatible and will "work" in an SDHC only device (that the Motorola Milestone appears to be).

> Do they need any special support from the OS?

Yes, in order to operate at the advertised higher speeds. "Use of UHS requires that the host device command the card to drop from 3.3-volt to 1.8-volt operation and select the 4-bit transfer mode." [Wikipedia - Secure Digital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital)

> Will I benefit from extra speed?

No, it will work like an ordinary SDHC Class 10 card.