# How to check that my Phone supports MicroSd Card SDXC UHS1 Bus Speed U30 card or not?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, external-sd, sd-card, performance, adoptable-storage

My device manufacturer technical specifications say that **Expandable storage supported is of 128GB FAT32** hope its slots must be supporting SDXC form factor not SDHC form factor and UHS1 U3 BUS SPEED

I want to purchase a card of 64GB or 128GB for my device and want to pre-confirm before purchasing

I have readed  answer to the question  [**microsd Speed necessary**](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/170347/what-is-the-minimum-microsd-speed-necessary-to-extend-the-storage-of-an-android/170359#170359) **that UHS  class U3 is not supported in all type of phones**

and link of    [Wikipedia: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#BUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Compatibility_2)  
also say that

> *"Older host devices generally do not support newer card formats, and even when they might support the bus interface used by the card.."*

and link of   [Wikipedia: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Bus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Bus) 
also say that

> "Use of UHS requires that the host device command the card to drop from 3.3-volt to 1.8-volt operation and select the 4-bit transfer mode."

This all confused me  so I want to confirm with online and other site whether integrated sdcard reader / host controllers specification  but  nothing could be founded for android and specially for my device

I want to know will the Micro SD-Card slot/host controller  will able to detect **SDXC UHS1 Bus speed class U3** cards or not and if detected can it perform on good speed or not?

Comment: SDXC UHS cards are always backward compatible, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SD_card#Compatibility_2 And also the UHS 1/2/3 description. There you can see for example that UHS2 card just have additional contacts that are ignored in older readers.

Comment: Similar situation: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/217557/218526

Comment: @Robert readed the wikipedia link `Older host devices generally do not support newer card formats, and even when they might support the bus interface used by the card..:'  thats why i m confused as i have android lolipop 5.1.1 and the device manufacturer say it supports 128GB fat32 cards ....i want to know that is the slot of my phone old host SDHC  or a UHS slot.... will it UHS1 be detected .. if yes then will it work in bus speed   UHS1 (109 Mbps bus speed) and U30 (30MBPs speed)...can it be seen on slot or any tool app command  to check the bus speed  supported.... uhs2 have more pins

Comment: @IrfanLatif `Similar situation: android.stackexchange.com/q/217557/218526 –` asked about the  capcity and  my  question is regarding bus speed UHS1 u3

Comment: `Older host devices generally do not support newer card formats, and even when they might support the bus interface used by the card..:' That statement is about SDHC/SDXC cards, not UHS. If your manual mentions 128 GB cards then it is has to have an SDXC reader.

Comment: @Androidquery the common point is: vendors don't reveal in detail the exact capabilities of host controllers they use in their devices. And the common conclusion is: no one is able to answer your question for sure unless they have tested the same SD card with the same device. // It's not always necessary to get a word to word answer, situations can be perceived from similar situations. You'll find scores of similar questions without any conclusion on web and this community as well.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Support for Ultra High Speed MicroSD cards](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/27074/support-for-ultra-high-speed-microsd-cards)

Comment: @Robert thank kindly post copy your comment to answer so I can vote or accept it

Comment: @IrfanLatif buddy thanks y u always mark my question duplicate it's good I read other links and I get some more knowledge... But the link u send asked for Motorola which supports  32gb SHDC card and my device supports 128 GB must be SDXC  card just want to confirm will it work in bus speed of uhs1 and u3 30mbps.. so it's different scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your phone specification state that it can support sd card >32gb (recent phones have support like 128gb, 512gb, 1tb or 2tb), then it supports SDXC.

Otherwise if it only supports 32gb and below, it only supports SDHC since there are no SDHC cards that has greater than 32gb of storage.

Regardless of the UHS-1 class, your phone can still detect micro SD cards that is SDXC compatible since it only specifies the card speed, not the compatibility. At the moment, no phone supports UHS-2 cards (not to be confused with UHS-1 class 2 or U2) but you can still use it since it is backwards compatible - though, you will not gain the optimal speed of that card.

Hope this helps!